# Abraham twitteroauth response parsing

Tags: php, twitter, oauth, response

I'm having a heck of a time figuring out how to parse out the error message when twitter throws an error.  Here's my code, which works fine to post a tweet:

```
$response = $twitteroauth->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $msg));
$e = $twitteroauth->http_code;
```

If `$e != 200`, I want to get twitter's error message.  If I `var_dump($response)`, I get something like

```
object(stdClass)#6 (1) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#7 (2) { ["code"]=> int(187) ["message"]=> string(21) "Status is a duplicate" } } }
```

How do I parse out that `message` `Status is a duplicate`?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to get the one message value then this should work. `$message = $response->errors[0]->message;`